# ToUnicodeEx() always returns 0 in python

Tags: python, winapi, ctypes, user32

I was trying to wrap C++ function ToUnicodeEx() in python, but it not works correctly, always returns 0.
On MSDN 0 means:

> The specified virtual key has no translation for the current state of the keyboard. Nothing was written to the buffer specified by pwszBuff.

```
from ctypes import *
_ToUnicodeEx = WinDLL('user32').ToUnicodeEx
_ToUnicodeEx.argtypes = [c_uint,c_uint,c_byte,c_wchar_p,c_int,c_uint,c_int]
_ToUnicodeEx.restype = c_int
def ToUn(vk,sc,kst,wfl,hkid):
    #b - is as in C++ pwszBuff 
    b = create_unicode_buffer(5)
    print(_ToUnicodeEx(vk,sc,kst,b,5,wfl,hkid))
    return b.value
#It must print "a" but prints "".
print(ToUn(65,0,0,0,1033))
```

Does i done something wrong, that it always returns 0?
P.S. In C# worked, with same arguments...

Comment: Since when was user32 written in C++?

Comment: Sorry, this was a typo.

Comment: You are ignoring most of the parameters to `ToUnicodeEx()`, or passing the wrong things entirely (`1033` itself is not a `HKL`; it has to be loaded first). What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: No, you're wrong, it works without loading in C#. I'm trying make it to write char with particular layout, by giving it its id.

Comment: The type of argument three is probably wrong, it should be a pointer to 256 byte array, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646322(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Yes, it looks like you are making this up without consulting the documentation. I suggest that you go back to basics and read the documentation much more closely.

Comment: @J.J.Hakala there are two arrays, the 256-byte input array that stores the keyboard state and the n-byte output array that stores the converted values, and they're only specifying the latter.

Comment: @BladeMight 1033 working without loading is an undocumented implementation detail and may not work on all versions of Windows. The documentation says to use the return of `LoadKeyboardLayout()`; you should do so. Are you sure passing `null` in C# also works for the other parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This more closely matches the MSDN documentation for ToUnicodeEx:

```
_ToUnicodeEx.argtypes = [c_uint,c_uint,POINTER(c_char),POINTER(c_wchar),c_int,c_uint,c_void_p]
```

`c_wchar_p` assumes null termination and `c_void_p` is appropriate for a handle.  The third parameter is supposed to be an 256-byte array and the last parameter is optional, so I tried this and got the result you want.  I'll admit I don't understand the intricacies of the function so I don't know what is appropriate for parameters.  I just met the type requirements.

```
from ctypes import *
_ToUnicodeEx = WinDLL('user32').ToUnicodeEx
_ToUnicodeEx.argtypes = [c_uint,c_uint,POINTER(c_char),POINTER(c_wchar),c_int,c_uint,c_void_p]
_ToUnicodeEx.restype = c_int
def ToUn(vk,sc,wfl,hkid):
    kst = create_string_buffer(256)
    b = create_unicode_buffer(5)
    print(_ToUnicodeEx(vk,sc,kst,b,5,wfl,hkid))
    return b.value
print(ToUn(65,0,0,None))
```

Output:

```
1
a
```