# Detect keyboard input with support of other languages from English

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, listener, pynput

I want to detect keystrokes in python in English and also in Hebrew ,I am using Python version 3.7.
I've already tried a lot of methods but but nothing works.
The problem is that no matter what I do it does not recognize the letters in a language other than English. And if I write in Hebrew it's still appears in the text file in English.
I need that even if I press Alt+Shift to changes my input to another language, it detect that language.

IMPORTANT: I need the Windows version.

Suppose this simple example:

```
# coding: utf-8
from pynput import keyboard
    
def on_press(key):
    with open('keys.txt', 'a',encoding ='utf-8') as file:
        file.write("{0}\n".format( str(key)))
       
with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

1. You need to translate the specified virtual-key code and keyboard state to the corresponding Unicode character or characters using the [`ToUnicodeEx` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-tounicodeex).
2. To do that (see the first part of code below, mainly `def ToUn`), you need to know the active input locale identifier (formerly called the keyboard layout). This isn't an easy task, and its solution is based on my own research, see the `def get_current_keyboard_layout()`. The main problem is that the [`GetKeyboardLayout` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeyboardlayout) returns [right value for the current thread merely under some shell/terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29217501/) (e.g. under *Python IDLE* or *Visual Studio Code* or *Visual Studio 2019*, …) and fails if launched from the `Run` dialog box (<kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) or from `cmd.exe` or from `pwsh.exe` or from any app which calls the `conhost.exe` helper process.
3. The original code is improved for extensively verbose output.

You can easy identify above three parts in the following (partially commented) script:

```
import os
import sys

if os.name != 'nt':
    raise Exception("IMPORTANT: I need the Windows version.") 
_verbose = ((len(sys.argv) > 1) and bool(sys.argv[1]))

### Translate the specified virtual-key code and keyboard state
#   to the corresponding Unicode character or characters.
#   learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-tounicodeex
### Adapted from
#   the solution to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38224277/
#   by https://stackoverflow.com/users/235698/mark-tolonen
###

from ctypes import (
    WinDLL, POINTER, create_string_buffer, create_unicode_buffer,
    c_int32, c_uint, c_uint, c_char, c_wchar, c_int, c_uint, c_void_p
    )
_ToUnicodeEx = WinDLL('user32').ToUnicodeEx
_ToUnicodeEx.argtypes = [
        c_uint,           # wVirtKey   virtual-key code to be translated
        c_uint,           # wScanCode  hardware scan code of ˙wVirtKey˙
        POINTER(c_char),  # lpKeyState current keyboard state (256-byte array)
        POINTER(c_wchar), # pwszBuff   buffer that receives translated chars
        c_int,            # cchBuff    size of the `pwszBuff` buffer (in chars)
        c_uint,           # wFlags     behavior of the function
        c_void_p          # dwhkl      input locale identifier
]
_ToUnicodeEx.restype = c_int


def ToUn(vk,sc,wfl,hkid):
    kst = create_string_buffer(256)
    b = create_unicode_buffer(5)
    if _ToUnicodeEx(vk,sc,kst,b,5,wfl,hkid):
        return b.value
    else:
        return chr( 0xFFFD) # Replacement Character


### Retrieve the active input locale identifier
#   (formerly called the keyboard layout)
#   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeyboardlayout
###
#   Method based on my own research; non-optimized, debugged on Windows 10… 
###

from ctypes import WinDLL
user32 = WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True)


def list_parents(pid, proclist):
    '''For verbose output'''
    aux = [_ for _ in proclist if _[0] == pid]
    if len( aux) > 0:
        auxcon = [x for x in proclist if (
                x[1] == aux[0][0] and x[2] == "conhost.exe")]
        list_parents(aux[0][1], proclist)
        print('parent', aux[0], auxcon if (len(auxcon) == 0) else auxcon[0])

def get_servant_conhost(pid, proclist):
    """Find “attendant” host process (conhost.exe)"""
    aux = [_ for _ in proclist if _[0] == pid]
    if len( aux) > 0:
        auxcon = [x for x in proclist if (
                x[1] == aux[0][0] and x[2] == "conhost.exe")]
        if len( auxcon) == 0:
            auxconret = get_servant_conhost(aux[0][1], proclist)
            return auxconret
        else:
            auxconret = auxcon[0]
            auxconret.append( aux[0][2])
            return auxconret
    else:
        return []


def get_conhost_threads():
    if sys.executable.lower().endswith('\\pythonw.exe'):
        return []
    import wmi
    c = wmi.WMI()
    w_where = ' or '.join([
        'Name like "p%.exe"',  # py.exe|python.exe|pwsh.exe|powershell.exe 
        'Name = "conhost.exe"',
        'Name = "cmd.exe"'
    ])
    w_properties = 'ProcessId, ParentProcessId, Name'
    w_wql = f'SELECT {w_properties} FROM Win32_Process where {w_where}'
    w_wqlaux = c.query(w_wql)
    proc_list = [[wqlitem.__getattr__('ProcessId'),
          wqlitem.__getattr__('ParentProcessId'),
          wqlitem.__getattr__('Name')] for wqlitem in w_wqlaux] 
    if _verbose:
        list_parents(os.getpid(), proc_list)
    servant_conhost = get_servant_conhost(os.getpid(), proc_list)
    if len( servant_conhost) == 0:
        return []
    else:
        try:
            w_where = f'ProcessHandle = {servant_conhost[0]}'
            w_wql = f'SELECT Handle FROM Win32_Thread WHERE {w_where}'
            w_wqlHandle = c.query(w_wql)
            wqlthreads = [x.__getattr__('Handle') for x in w_wqlHandle]
        except:
            wqlthreads = []
    return wqlthreads


# required if run from `cmd` or from the `Run` dialog box (`<WinKey>+R`) 
conhost_threads = get_conhost_threads()
if _verbose:
    print( 'threads', conhost_threads)
                                    

def get_current_keyboard_layout():
    foregroundWindow  = user32.GetForegroundWindow();
    foregroundProcess = user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(int(foregroundWindow), 0);
    keyboardLayout    = user32.GetKeyboardLayout(int(foregroundProcess));
    keyboardLayout0   = user32.GetKeyboardLayout(int(0));
    if keyboardLayout == 0  or len(conhost_threads):                 
        if keyboardLayout == 0:
            keyboardLayout = keyboardLayout0
        for thread in conhost_threads:
            aux = user32.GetKeyboardLayout( int(thread))
            if aux != 0 and aux != keyboardLayout0:
                if _verbose:
                    print('thread', thread)
                keyboardLayout = aux
                break
    return keyboardLayout


### improved original code
#   Detect keyboard input with support of other languages from English
#   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71431386/
###
#   written for extensively verbose output
###

import unicodedata
from pynput import keyboard
last_key = keyboard.Key.media_next  # improbable last key pressed


def on_press(key):
    global last_key
    if isinstance(key, keyboard.Key):
        if key == keyboard.Key.space:
            c_hkl = get_current_keyboard_layout()
            chklp = f'{(c_hkl & 0xFFFFFFFF):08x}'
            # 0x39 = SpaceBarScanCode https://kbdlayout.info/kbduk/scancodes
            print(key.value.char,
                  f'{key.value.vk} ({key.value.vk:02x})',
                  f'{0x39} ({0x39:02x})',
                  f'{c_hkl:10} ({chklp})',
                  unicodedata.name(key.value.char, '?')
                  )
        else:
            if last_key != key:
                print( f'{"":39}', key.value, key.name )
                last_key = key
    else:
        c_hkl = get_current_keyboard_layout()
        chklp = f'{(c_hkl & 0xFFFFFFFF):08x}'
        c_char = ToUn(key.vk, key._scan, 0, c_hkl)
        print(c_char,
              f'{key.vk} ({key.vk:02x})',
              f'{key._scan} ({key._scan:02x})',
              f'{c_hkl:10} ({chklp})',
              unicodedata.name(c_char[0], '?')
              )


def on_release(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:     
        return False             # Stop listener


print('\n  vk_code scancode   HKL dec (HKL hexa) character name')
with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    x=listener.join()
```

**Output** (tested mainly the <kbd>F</kbd> key for different keyboard layouts  (input languages) switched cyclically by  <kbd>LeftAlt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>): `\SO\71431386.py`

```
  vk_code scancode   HKL dec (HKL hexa) character name
f 70 (46) 33 (21)   67438601 (04050809) LATIN SMALL LETTER F
                                        <164> alt_l
                                        <160> shift
ф 70 (46) 33 (21) -265092071 (f0330419) CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER EF
                                        <164> alt_l
                                        <160> shift
f 70 (46) 33 (21)   67437573 (04050405) LATIN SMALL LETTER F
                                        <164> alt_l
                                        <160> shift
φ 70 (46) 33 (21) -266992632 (f0160408) GREEK SMALL LETTER PHI
                                        <164> alt_l
                                        <160> shift
f 70 (46) 33 (21)   67438601 (04050809) LATIN SMALL LETTER F
  32 (20) 57 (39)   67438601 (04050809) SPACE
                                        <27> esc
```